# AWS boto3 list codepipelines

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I am trying to list all the pipelines on AWS, and am passing nextToken as session token.
However this does not seem to work, any ideas?

```
import boto3


def list_pipelines():
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id="AKIAJMO63R4OAY6HMXUQ",
        aws_secret_access_key="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"
    )
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    print credentials
    code_pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')
    pipelines = code_pipeline.list_pipelines(nextToken=credentials.token)
    for i in pipelines:
        print i


def main():
    list_pipelines()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter nextToken, value: None, type: <type 'NoneType'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>
```

Answer (score 3):

You misinterpreted the meaning of `nextToken`. It is used for pagination. The first time, you call without the `nextToken` parameter. If the response has `hasMoreResults` set to `True`, then in the next call use the `marker` returned in the response to the previous call.

```
  while pipelines['hasMoreResults']:
    pipelines = code_pipeline.list_pipelines(nextToken=pipelines['marker'])
```

[List Pipelines](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/datapipeline.html#DataPipeline.Client.list_pipelines)

**Request Syntax**

```
response = client.list_pipelines(
    marker='string'
)
```

**Parameters**

> marker (string) -- The starting point for the results to be returned.
>   For the first call, this value should be empty. As long as there are
>   more results, continue to call ListPipelines with the marker value
>   from the previous call to retrieve the next set of results.

**Response Syntax**

```
{
    'pipelineIdList': [
        {
            'id': 'string',
            'name': 'string'
        },
    ],
    'marker': 'string',
    'hasMoreResults': True|False
}
```

**marker (string)**

> The starting point for the next page of results. To view the next page
>   of results, call ListPipelinesOutput again with this marker value. If
>   the value is null, there are no more results.

**hasMoreResults (boolean)**

> Indicates whether there are more results that can be obtained by a
>   subsequent call.